# Link or tutoriel about a good example to create a new view in django admin? It means a form - a queryset?

Tags: django-admin

I read the documentation of django admin.
I don't find a good example about step to do a complete addition of a new view in django admin.

It means, a view - a form - a queryset set - a template

I have the feeling to spend ages to try to do something by myself.

Find only simple example by playing with the attribute:

change_list_template
form
filter
....

or django-plugin you don't know the goals

Answer (score 0):

A good example here :

- definition of a new template copy of change_list.html
- in the admin.py addition in the concerned class of new 
  definition of def Change_list_view
- use property chnage_list_template

https://maketips.net/tip/226/django-add-additional-range-filter

Answer (score 0):

I'm very confused as to what you are asking, but I'll try to answer:

If you're trying to add in a new view to the Django Admin Interface, as in, a new view to administrate a model, you just need to register the model in the model's app's admin.py file

If you're trying to add in a new view THROUGH the Django admin interface, that isn't going to work unless you are using a Content Management System.

The Django admin interface is essentially just a way to easily interact with your database. If you're trying to actually create content for your site, you are going to need to create a view in your views.py file for your app. I'd recommend looking up a video tutorial on YouTube for starting with Django.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Sure I feel I need to understand more the framework. Just a few examples, I was able to add some date  fields  in the change_list.html , in the log I see the parameter : example ?q=&updatedDate__gte=2018-05-18&updatedDate__lt=2018-05-26&csrfmiddlewaretoken=LvONoEuVTqVuQPshQAyPpnjbcyW216pThhF9N1HGwR3RSr3gCXdnxk6VnSEgdHxC HTTP/1.1  but after it's  transform in /?e=1  , i 'm not able to pass simple parameter ...

Comment: I'm very confused as to what you mean by this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: For example: in the change_list.html in the block search, I remove {% search_form cl %} and I add my own form based on the same id ( form id="changelist-search" method="get".. and I add three fields:  a input text ( I name Id=q as it set the url0 and two dates fields __gte / __lt. This works only if i filled the three fields otherwise by looking for only by the text fields in the url I see /?e=1 . Is it because i made a mix with the search_fields in admin .py.